# Convert INT to FLOAT

Tags: sql, casting

I have this query:

```
SELECT sl.sms_prefix, sum( sl.parts ) , cp.country_name, CAST(SUM(sl.parts) AS NUMERIC(10,4)) * CAST(cp.price AS NUMERIC(10,4))
FROM sms_log sl, sms_transaction st, country_prefix cp
WHERE st.customer_id =1
AND st.sendtime >=1329865200
AND st.sendtime <=1330037999
AND st.sms_trans_id = sl.trans_id
AND sl.sms_prefix = cp.prefix
AND st.customer_id = cp.customer_id
GROUP BY sl.sms_prefix
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Result:

```
sms_prefix  sum( sl.parts )     country_name    price   total
==================================================================================
45            2                        Denmark   0.01   0.019999999552965
63            3                        Philippines   2  6
```

As you see the `"total"` is not correct for `Denmark` because `sum( sl.parts )=2` Multiply with `0.01` the total should be `0.02`.

Price field is `FLOAT` how I can CAST the total to float?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In oracle db there is a trick for casting int to float (I suppose, it should also work in mysql):

```
select myintfield + 0.0 as myfloatfield from mytable
```

Comment: don't forget about arithmetic operations priority, sum has lower priority than multiplication. (sum( sl.parts )+0.0) * cp.price would be more correct.

Comment: Yes, I need the SUM happen before multiplication

Comment: @alkhader - Heximal means that by not specifying brackets, you currently have `SUM(sl.parts) + (0.0 * cp.price)`, which is not what you want.  Putting brackets where Heximal says will implicitly cast your SUM to a float, and then multiply it by `cp.price`.

Answer (score 49):

While @Heximal's answer works, I don't personally recommend it.

This is because it uses *implicit* casting.  Although you didn't type `CAST`, either the `SUM()` or the `0.0` need to be cast to be the same data-types, before the `+` can happen.  In this case the order of precedence is in your favour, and you get a float on both sides, and a float as a result of the `+`.  But `SUM(aFloatField) + 0` does not yield an INT, because the `0` is being *implicitly* cast to a FLOAT.

I find that in most programming cases, it is much preferable to be *explicit*.  Don't leave things to chance, confusion, or interpretation.

If you want to be explicit, I would use the following.

```
CAST(SUM(sl.parts) AS FLOAT) * cp.price
-- using MySQL CAST FLOAT  requires 8.0
```

I won't discuss whether NUMERIC or FLOAT *(fixed point, instead of floating point)* is more appropriate, when it comes to rounding errors, etc.  I'll just let you google that if you need to, but FLOAT is so massively misused that there is a lot to read about the subject already out there.

You can try the following to see what happens...

```
CAST(SUM(sl.parts) AS NUMERIC(10,4)) * CAST(cp.price AS NUMERIC(10,4))
```

Comment: Thanks Dems, when I tried CAST(SUM(sl.parts) AS NUMERIC(10,4)) * CAST(cp.price AS NUMERIC(10,4)) , it give a Syntax error right syntax to use near 'FLOAT)

Comment: @alkhader - Your snippet doesn't include the word `FLOAT` - so you need to show the rest of your query.  It may just be a missing `)` or `,` from a preceding statement.

Comment: Thanks Dems, I have updated my original POST with the query I used.

Comment: This is INCORRECT MySQL!! `CAST`ing to `FLOAT` is **not allowed**. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast . Even `CAST(5 AS FLOAT)` produces errors.